# split list based on the variable values in different list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

`List1=[2,4,3]`
`List2=[1,2,1,3,2,1,5,4,1]`

Need to generate output like this:

`ResultList=[[1,2],[1,3,2,1],[5,4,1]]`

Need help!!!

Comment: Hello, churchurnaan. What have you tried so far? Also please see [mre].

Comment: ```for j in List1:
    out=[List2[i:i + j] for i in range(0, len(List2), j)]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
result_list=[]
a = 0
for i in list1:
    result_list.append(list2[a:a+i])
    a += i
```

Answer (score 1):

The below should work

```
list1 = [2,4,3] 
list2 = [1,2,1,3,2,1,5,4,1]

offset = 0
data = []
for x in list1:
    data.append(list2[offset:offset+x])
    offset += x
print(data)
```

output

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3, 2, 1], [5, 4, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice

lengths = [2, 4, 3]
numbers = iter([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 1])

lists = [list(islice(numbers, length)) for length in lengths]

print(lists)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3, 2, 1], [5, 4, 1]]
>>>
```